# How to show that $p \nmid a \Rightarrow \gcd(p,a)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to show that $p \nmid a \Rightarrow \gcd(p,a)=1$?

If we have canonical representations of $p= q_1^{b_1} \cdots q_n^{b_n}$ and  $a= r_1^{c_1} \cdots r_k^{c_k}$, then because $p \nmid a$, $q_i \neq r_j$ for all $i=1, \dots, n$ and $j=1, \dots k \Rightarrow \gcd(p,a)=1$.

Comment: This problem is poorly stated.  It's true that if $p = q_1^{b_1}\dots q_n^{b_n}$ and $a=r_1^{c_1}\dots r_k^{c_k}$ with $q_i \neq r_j$ then gcd$(p,a)=1$.  But it's not true that if $p$ doesn't divide $a$ then gcd$(p,a)=1$.  For instance, 6 doesn't divide 10 but gcd$(6,10)=2$.  Ask yourself, is it possible for gcd$(q_i,r_j)>1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem must have come from a source that assumes $p$ is prime.

That means your second paragraph is barking up the wrong tree.

Suppose $\gcd(a,p)=m\ne 1$.  Then $m$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $p$.  That means $m$ divides $a$ and $m$ divides $p$.  If $m$ divides $p$ and $p$ is prime, then $m = \text{either }1\text{ or }p$.  We've ruled out $1$, so $m=p$.  If $m$ divides $a$ and $m=p$, then $p$ divides $a$.  But you ruled that out at the beginning.